# can't access to supabase in vercel deployed product Nextjs14

Tags: next.js, prisma, vercel, supabase

I am creating web app with Nextjs14, prisma, and supabase (postgreSQL). in localhost it works well, but I deployed it in vercel and then errors happen.
I did integration in vercel to connect to supabase.
The endpoints I used are here:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/player/attendance (for local, it works)
https://*****.vercel.app/api/player/attendance (for vercel, doesn't work)
```

shema.prisma

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

.env (I replaced my own ones)

```
DATABASE_URL="postgres://[db-user]:[db-password]@aws-0-[aws-region].pooler.supabase.com:5432/[db-name]"
```

I found this article [PGBouncer and IPv4 Deprecation](https://github.com/orgs/supabase/discussions/17817)
but my url  already used like this...right?
and I also tried postman with this endpoint(https://*****.vercel.app/api/player/attendance)
and the return was

```
{
    "message": "Error",
    "error": {
        "name": "PrismaClientInitializationError",
        "clientVersion": "5.9.1"
    }
}
```

so the problem is the connection with supabase right?

here is the errors from vercel.I think that the first error makes the last two ones because I use 'map' with the data of supabase

```
[GET] /api/player/attendance status=500
```

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map') at l (/var/task/.next/server/app/page.js:2:4654) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
```

```
 [Error: An error occurred in the Server Components render. The specific message is omitted in production builds to avoid leaking sensitive details. A digest property is included on this error instance which may provide additional details about the nature of the error.] { digest: '3113241611' }
```

so what is my problem?
thanks

Comment: Do you get any error logs when deploying to Vercel? If so, please include the error logs

Comment: @hersh
yes of curse. I added errors in the descriptions. Please check it! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your Prisma client isn't initializing correctly. Your database URL is also not set up to use connection pooling with Supavisor and it's using the wrong port. Here's how you can fix both -

1. Update your database URL to append `?pgbouncer=true` as per [prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/overview/databases/supabase#specific-considerations)
2. Update the port from `5432` to `6543`.

After making the above two changes, your database URL would look like -

`DATABASE_URL="postgres://[db-user]:[db-password]@aws-0-[aws-region].pooler.supabase.com:6543/[db-name]?pgbouncer=true"`

To ensure Prisma client is initialized correctly [as per prisma docs](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/help-and-troubleshooting/help-articles/vercel-caching-issue)-

1. Update the `build` command in your `package.json` -

   `"build": "prisma generate && next build"`
2. Add a new command in the `scripts` object in your `package.json`

   `"postinstall": "prisma generate"`
3. Update your Vercel's [build and output settings](https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/more/help-and-troubleshooting/help-articles/vercel-caching-issue#:%7E:text=Within%20your%20project%27s%20dashboard%2C%20go%20to%20the%20Settings%20tab%20and%20find%20the%20General%20section.%20In%20that%20section%20you%20will%20find%20a%20box%20labeled%20Build%20%26%20Development%20Settings%20that%20contains%20an%20input%20field%20named%20Build%20Command%3A), override the **build command** to the following -

   `npx prisma generate && next build`